# how to substitute null instead of strictly typed parameter of method for tests javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, types, null

I have some method:

```
someMethod(userId: string): string {

 if(userId === null) {
   throw SomeError
 }

 ...
}
```

and test:

```
it('#someMetho with invalid parameters', () => {
        someMethod(null).catch((error: any) => {
           expect(error).toEqual(SomeError);
        });
    });
```

And got a warning that the Argument of type **null** is not assignable to parameter of type **string**.

How to avoid this warning in test?

Comment: `someMethod(userId: string | null)`

Comment: I can not change the source code

Comment: Then you shouldn't be testing it.